# Cannot attach to an existing Selenium session via geckodriver

Tags: python, session, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

After upgrading to geckodriver I'm unable to reuse my Selenium's sessions. Here's my setup:

I have a `start_browser.py` script, which launches a Firefox instance and prints a port to connect to, like:

```
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
print browser.service.port
wait_forever()
```

... and another script, which tries to connect to the existing instance via Remote driver:

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
caps['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://localhost:{port}'.format(port=port),
        desired_capabilities=caps)
```

But it seems to be trying to launch a new session, and failing with a message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Session is already started
```

Is there an ability to just attach to the existing session, like in previous versions of Selenium? Or is this an intended behaviour of geckodriver (hope not)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, so unless anyone comes up with more elegant solution, here's a quick dirty hack:

```
class SessionRemote(webdriver.Remote):
    def start_session(self, desired_capabilities, browser_profile=None):
        # Skip the NEW_SESSION command issued by the original driver
        # and set only some required attributes
        self.w3c = True

driver = SessionRemote(command_executor=url, desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.session_id = session_id
```

The bad thing is that it still doesn't work, complaining that it doesn't know the `moveto` command, but at least it connects to a launched browser.

*Update*: Well, geckodriver seems to lack some functionality at the moment, so if you guys are going to keep using Firefox, just downgrade it to a version which supports old webdriver (45 plays fine), and keep an eye on tickets like https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285 .

Comment: what of it now?

Answer (score 0):

You can reconnect to a session by using the session id.

```
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
print browser.service.port
wait_forever()

# get the ID and URL from the browser
url = browser.command_executor._url
session_id = browser.session_id

# Connect to the existing instance
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url,desired_capabilities={})
driver.session_id = session_id
```

Comment: Still no luck. It crashes before I even can assign the session, in the `webdriver.Remote()` constructor. Current implementation seems to have new session creation hardcoded: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L177 . Any thoughts?

Comment: @AlexMorozov That shouldn't be the problem as it works for me. The only difference is that I'm not using `marionette`. Did you try it with the `capabilities` for the `webdriver.Remote` call as `{}` or did you add new `capabilities`?

Comment: Tried both `capabilities` options. Actually it have been working for me too until a recent version of Firefox deprecated the old driver and made a `marionette` the only way of interacting with the browser. So the question is how to reattach to a session considering new conditions.

Comment: How do you get the session id for a browser you launched manually?

Comment: This doesn't actually works due to the inability to set the session_id, because you don't get webdriver instance, so nothing can be patched. @Cerin the session ID is not on the browser, it's on the geckodriver. I think you're looking for the gekocdriver --connec-existing parameter. It does suffer the very same problema about session ID already started. The way is to patch the start command like selected answer does.