# selenium: finding it difficult to open a new session in an existing browser window via geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to develop scripts that are memory efficient. I believe using a single instance(window) of firefox would speed up pace execution of scripts and decrease space complexity and therefore increase efficiency of selenium scripts in python (by enabling use of more scripts simultaneously). It would also make browser sessions more organized and easy to use.

I have tried using `--connect-existing` argument to the options variable

```
options.add_argument("--connect-existing")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

but still saw a new window open.

Tried these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964479
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73964036/20356446

But they too fail run